# Strategy for multi branch Jenkins and test(CI/CD)

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

**What I want**
I have a code repository in *Gitea* with several branches. If someone request merge, Jenkins workflow will be triggerred and will run the test on that branch with output report.

**What I've done**
A basic workflow of build and test successfully

**What I've tried**

1. 'Generic Webhook Trigger' plugin: when someone pushes code, the Jenkins workflow will run (instead of clicking 'Build Now' manually, but only run master branch)
2. 'Git Parameter' plugin: I can select which branch to run manually
3. I find a multibranch pipeline when creating project, but the workflow seems different from freestyle workflow, like no step to put test script. I don't know if I can add steps in 'Jenkinsfile'...

**What I'm confused**
I don't know which direction is right or is there any more convenient ways?
Please explain in details. It's my first time to use Jenkins... Thanks!

Comment: do you need any more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! MultiBranch Pipeline looks good to me. I'm working on that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are proceeding with in direction, We can choose between multi-branch pipeline/pipeline/free-style job in Jenkins based on git branching model.

We will use Multibranch pipeline if we have separate branch for every environment(separate branch for dev/sit/prod).

We will use Pipeline if we used to build any branch (feature/bug). We can add different stages and steps in Jenkinsfile.

Freestyle job is for basic operations, Better to use Pipeline over Freestyle where we can have Jenkinsfile as a code.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a job, there are many options which jenkins provides based on your use case which you can select. I would elaborate each in detail:
[image]
[image]

- **Freestyle Project** :
  The main aim of the freestyle project is implementing, developing, or running simple jobs such as enabling you to specify the version control system from where you need to extract code and build it and call tests. 
  It requires users to manually create jobs, then manually fill in the details through a web browser. This requires additional effort to create and manage jobs to test and build multiple projects, it also keeps the configuration of a job to build/test/deploy separate from the actual code being built/tested/deployed. This prevents users from applying their existing CI/CD best practices to the job configurations themselves.
  If you are not using Jenkinsfile for your configuration it means you are mostly Freestyle project
- **Pipeline** :
  With pipeline everything is executed via pipeline as a code.
  Pipeline Project is better either to set up a CI/CD pipeline or to define the deployment pipeline as code. The pipeline project is suitable to build pipelines for complex jobs whereas the freestyle project is suitable for simple jobs.
  With the Pipeline plugin, you  can implement a project’s entire build/test/deploy pipeline in a Jenkinsfile and store that alongside their code, treating their pipeline as another piece of code checked into source control.
  You can completely define the pipeline as per your requirement with stages as per your need and have this completely via groovy code 
  You can have a blue ocean view when using pipeline and example looks like below based on the stages you configured 
  [image]
  Another example how pipeline is used:

[image]

To start using Pipeline Refer : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

- **Multibranch Pipeline** :
  A normal pipeline job is meant for building a single branch from the SCM and deploy to a single environment. The Multibranch Pipeline project type enables you to implement different Jenkinsfiles for different branches of the same project. In a Multibranch Pipeline project, Jenkins automatically discovers, manages and executes Pipelines for branches which contain a Jenkinsfile in source control.
  For more info Refer: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

  **Next steps / Direction** :
  Which one to use totally depends on the workflow you need.
  With Pipeline (Jenkinsfile)  you have the ability to add stages, steps, write your functions, execute scripts, create shared libraries and have Pipeline as a code. You also have possibilty to generate pipeline script snippet using the Snippet generator tool which will help you learn the Pipeline script code. 
  So considering many advantages and CI practices, I would prefer or recommend to use Pipeline for the job.